# Use of Spring Assert.notnull in production code

Tags: java, spring, assert, autowired

I have inherited an application that uses Spring Autowiring and each autowired constructor is littered with Assert.notNull() to check each argument before proceding.

I can't see how constructor autowiring would ever let these arguments be null so these assertions seem redundant and make the code look messy.

I appreciate it may be useful for unit testing where the args are manually injected, but I think that a NPE in testing would be enough to indicate that the test is not properly initialised.

Before I go and 'tidy' the code I thought I'd just ask whether I have missed something?

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's just additional prevention - autowiring is a feature of container, separated from your code and it can be disabled at any time. In that way you can explicitly define constructor's contract.

Let's say that someone disabled autowiring on that particular class and replaced it with:

```
  <bean id="myBean" class="com.my.company.BeanImpl">
    <constructor-arg name="someService">
        <null />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

I think that this is the point you are missing :)

Comment: Highly unlikely in my system but I'll accept that if someone is intent on abusing it then the asserts would stop them doing so. All the same, I sense a code tidy coming on...